# error: Failed dependencies: libpq.so.5()(64bit) is needed by pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7.x86_64

Tags: linux, postgresql

when i am going to install

```
[postgres@m rpm]$ rpm -ivh pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libpq.so.5()(64bit) is needed by pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7.x86_64
```

this error occur

but

```
[postgres@m rpm]$ locate libpq.so.5
/home/postgres/postgresql-10.4/src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.so.5
/home/postgres/postgresql-10.4/src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.so.5.10
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5
/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5.10
```

how can i fix this ?

best regard 
thanks

Comment: Is the libpq you have 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

the postgresql-lib was lost

```
[root@t9psql03 rpmadd]# rpm -qa | grep postgresql-libs
[root@t9psql03 rpmadd]# yum install postgresql-libs
```

then solve

```
[root@t9psql03 PostgreSQL10]# rpm -ivh pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:pg_statsinfo-10.0-1.pg10.rhel7   ################################# [100%]
```